# Snow Leopard .htaccess issue

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, apache-http-server

I'm running into an issue on Snow Leopard.  I am just using the standard Apache2 that came with it but it doesn't seem to want to use my .htaccess file.  Here is the appropriate part of my httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All AuthConfig
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</Directory>
```

And here is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, but at this point, I just cant see it!

All it's doing is allowing me to not have the index.php file, this worked on Leopard and isn't working in Snow Leopard.  What am I missing?

Comment: Questions about server configuration (such as Apache) are probably better suited for http://serverfault.com

Comment: oops!  didn't even realize that existed!  Should I just reask there or can you guys move it?

Comment: Don't re-ask; it will be moved if people think it's required.

Comment: Did you *upgrade* to SL, or is this another machine/new installation?

Comment: And does any of the hints at http://superuser.com/questions/53303/htaccess-not-working-on-mac-when-copied-but-works-from-a-ntfs-partition/ work for you?

Comment: This is a full install of SL not an upgrade and I tried the hints from above to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) extension installed and enabled?  It might have been removed/changed when you updated.

Comment: yep, mod_rewrite is loaded

Answer (score 0):

hey, I had the same problem on my new computer and I found out it is because Snow Leopard automatically created a new config under /etc/apache2/users/, so go ahead and change the content like:

```
<Directory "/Users/<username>/Sites/">
  Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Same prob here. My fix included both editing the "yourusername.conf" file as well as relaxing some of the similar restrictions about half way down the apache2/httpd.conf file.

Hope this helps.